# Label at the end of document is lost, bug?

Tags: memoir, labels, debugging

I'm having a long document in `memoir` at the end of which I set a `label`, and so far it has worked. I did some changes to my document, at unrelated places, and suddenly I'm getting the warning that that reference is undefined. The last page is full up to the end (with a `biblatex`-bibliography). When I, for testing purposes, add some more text, my document grows by one page, and the reference is back, when I delete that extra line, the document shrinks by one page and the reference is lost again. This looks like a bug to me, but I'm not sure, and I'm not sure either which is the concerned package. Now I can just make a temporary command into which I just write the number of my last page, and hope that with further changes my document gets longer or shorter again, and I don't need it anymore, but if there really is a bug, then what would be the right thing to do about it?

Edit:

When I tried to produce a MWE from scratch I couldn't reproduce the problem, but now I just came across another case of the same problem which offered itself to be minimised, sure it's not a MWE, and sure the bibliography contained is outright broken, however for the purpose of identifying the bug it should suffice:

```
\documentclass[oldfontcommands,a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}%For demo only.
%\RequirePackage{verbatim} %For multi line comments
\usepackage{filecontents}
%%% Font Setup
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}

%%%Page setup
\quarkmarks
\setpagecc{24.1cm}{16.4cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{17cm}{11.8cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\newcommand{\chapterfirstpage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterlastpage}{}
\newcommand{\shorttitle}{}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\textsc{\shorttitle}}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{\textsc{\theauthor}}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\textit{pp. \chapterfirstpage{}–\chapterlastpage{}}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{\textit{pp. \chapterfirstpage{}–\chapterlastpage{}}}{}{}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\aftertoctitle{}
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph} %Get numbering of headings back
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty} % first page no page number
\counterwithout{section}{chapter} %remove chapter number from headings

%%%Footnote Setup
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\setfootnoterule{3pt}{0.125\columnwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

%%%Section header setup:
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries}
\setaftersubsecskip{1sp}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{1sp}
\setparaheadstyle{}
\setafterparaskip{1sp}

%%% Change section number formatting 
\setsecnumformat{\csname ts#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\tssection}{\thesection\qquad\quad}
\newcommand{\tssubsection}{\thesubsection\qquad}
\newcommand{\tssubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection\qquad}
\newcommand{\tsparagraph}{\theparagraph\enspace}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@Book { astangahrdaya ,
shorthand = {Aṣṭāṅgahṛdaya},
title = {Aṣṭāṅgahṛdaya of Vāgbhaṭa. The romanised text accompanied by line and word indexes} ,
%shorttitle = {aṣṭāṅgahṛdaya} ,
editor = {Rahul Peter Das and Ronald Eric Emmerick},
%year = 1998,
location = {Groningen} ,
publisher = {Egbert Forsten. 1998},
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@Book { bharuci ,
title = {Bharuci's Commentary on the Manusmrti} ,
%shorttitle = { bharuci } ,
volumes =  2 ,
editor = {{J. D. M. Derrett}},
location = {Wiesbaden. 1973},
%year = 1973 ,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book { bṛhatsaṃhitā ,
title = {{Bṛhatsaṃhitā of Varāhamihira}},
key = {bṛhatsaṃhitā},
%shorttitle = {bṛhatsaṃhitā},
editor = {{ H. Kern. }},
location = { Calcutta }, 
publisher = {{Baptist mission press. 1865}}, 
%date = 1865,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book { carakasaṃhitā , 
title = {{Carakasaṃhitā of Agniveśa revised by Caraka and Dṛḍhabala }}, 
subtitle = {{ With the Commentary [āyurvedadīpikā] of Cakrapāṇidatta }},
editor= {{Jādavaji Trikamji Ācārya}},
%edition = {3rd ed.},
edition = 3,
location = {{Bombay}},
publisher =  {{Nirnaya Sagar press}}, 
date = 1941,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}


@book { chāndogyopaniṣad,
title = {Chāndogyopaniṣad},
series = {{Eighteen Principal Upaniṣads }},
volume = 1,
editor = {{ V.~P. Limaye and R.~D. Vadekar}},
location = {Poona},
publisher = {{Vaidika Saṃ\-śodhana Maṇḍala. 1958}}, 
%year = 1958,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book { jātakamālā,
title = {{Jātakamālā of Āryaśūra}},
editor ={{ Hendrik Kern}},
series = {{Harvard Oriental series}}, 
volume = 1,
location = {{Cambridge, Massachusetts}},
publisher = {{ Harvard University Press}},
year = 1943,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book {mahābhārata,
title = {{Mahābhārata}},
editor = {{V. Sukthankar, with the cooperation of S. K. Belvalkar, A. B. Gajendragadkar,V.  Kane, R. D. Karmarkar, P. L. Vaidya, S. Winternitz, R. Zimmerman, and other scholars}},
note = {{illustrated by Shrimant Balasaheb Pant Pratinidhi. (Since 1943 ed. S. Belvalkar).  19 Vols.}},
location = {{Poona}},
publisher = {{Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute}},
year = {{1927-1959}},
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@misc { Niśvāsatattvasaṃhitā,
title = {Niśvāsatattvasaṃhitā},
note = {{National Archives Kathmandu (NAK) MS~1--227, Nepal German Manuscript Preservation Project
        (NGMPP) Reel No.\thinspace A~41/14.  Palm--leaf, Folios 117,
        early Nepalese (Kuṭilā) script. Described by Hara Prasād Śāstri 
        (1905:lxxvii and 137--140). The verse and chapter numeration used in footnotes is that of Goodall's edition in progress.}},
}

@book {skandapurāṇa ,
title = {{Skandapurāṇa. Vol. IIA:  Adhyāyas 26--31.14. The Vārāṇasī Cycle}},
editor = {{ Hans T.~Bakker and Harunaga Isaacson}},
location = { Groningen},
publisher = {{Egbert Forston}}, 
year = 2004,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book {suśrutasaṃhitā ,
title = { suśrutasaṃhitā of Suśruta with the Commentaries of Dalhaṇa (Nibandhasaṅgraha) and Gayadāsa (Nyāyacandrikā, only on \textit{Nidānasthāna})},
editor = {Vaidya Jadavji Trikamji Acharya and Narayan Ram Acharya},
year = {1992 (Reprint)},
location = {Varanasi/Delhi},
publisher = {Chaukhambha Orientalia},
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book { tantrāloka ,
title = {{ Tantrāloka of Abhi\-nava\-gupta with Commentary [ -viveka] of Rājānaka Jaya\-ratha}}, 
editor = {Madhusūdan Kaul Śāstrī},
series = {KSTS},
number = {23, 28, 30, 35, 29, 41, 47, 59, 52, 57 and 58},
location = {Bombay and Srinagar}, 
year = {1918-38},
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

@book { vaikhānasadharmasūtra ,
%shorttitle = {vaikhānasadharmasūtra},
title = {{Vaikh\=anasag\d{r}hyas\=utra and Vaikh\=anasadharmas\=utra. The Domestic Rules of the Vaikh\=anasa School belonging to the Black Yajurveda}},
editor = {W. Caland},
location = {Calcutta},
publisher = {{The Asiatic Society of Bengal}},
year = 1927,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}   



@book { yājñavalkyasmṛti,
title =  {{Yājñavalkyasmṛti of Yogīśvara Yājña\-valkya with the Commentary [Vīramitrodaya] of Mitra Miśra and [Mitākṣarā] of Vi\-jñāneśvara}},
subtitle = {{testsubtitle}},
editor = {{Nārāyaṇa Śāstrī Khiste and Jagannātha Śāstrī Hośiṅga}}, 
series = {{ Chowkhambha Sanskrit Series }},
number = {{62}},
location = { Benares},
publisher = {{Chowkhambha Sanskrit Series Office}}, 
year = 1929,
options = {useeditor = false}, 
}

\end{filecontents}

%%%Bibliography Setup

\usepackage[notes,short,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt} % no empty line between bib entries
%\addbibresource{prim.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\author{Some Author}
\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
\label{chX.firstpage}
\renewcommand{\chapterfirstpage}{\pageref{chX.firstpage}}
\renewcommand{\chapterlastpage}{\pageref{chX.lastpage}}
\renewcommand{\shorttitle}{\thetitle}%Or something shorter if necessary to fit page headers


\maketitle
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents*

\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2] Some more text to add a footnote on.\footnote{This is a footnote} And again some more text.\footnote{And this time a much longer footnote. Longer than one line. Still longer so we reach the line break.}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[3]
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\lipsum[4]
\nocite{*}%

\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, heading=subbibliography]

\label{chX.lastpage}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A document to work with would be nice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I guess I would have to try to reproduce it in a MWE, not sure how to do that. I'm suspecting it might have to do with biblatex, so then I would create a document with a testing bibliography that exactly fills one page, and put a label at the end?

Comment: That's basically the name of the game, yes ;-)

Comment: I have had a similar problem a few times in the past, but I can't find one right now. I never tracked down the cause, but a work round for me was to add something that is invisible after the final label, for example a `~`. If that messes up the format of the last page, you could try something like `\hskip 0pt`, `\kern 0pt`, `\mbox{}` or whatever.

Comment: Or try [pageslts](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)?

Comment: Why are you using a label to keep tract of the last page then memoir has build in features to give you that?

Comment: @daleif Because the example file is only one chapter of an edited volume, with each chapter having its own page range in the footer. I have not yet decided how I'll glue together the entire volume in the end, but when, at an earlier stage, I was asked to produce a draft of the whole book this solution worked for me. I'll look into the lastpage counter provided by memoir if I can use it.

Comment: @muk.li that was not particularly obvious from your question.

Comment: Also if you want a label at the end you may have to drop a `\clearpage` in advance, reset the page number by `-1` and *then* set the label. Just to make sure that everything *is* formatted.

Comment: @daleif Can you give the “official” answer with the `memoir` facility?

Comment: @egreg given the ops info I don't think there is an official memoir solution. We track the last page and the sheetsequence but it is not clear if any of the is usable to the op